# svg with style in old IE

Tags: javascript, svg, stylesheet, visio

For my project, I need to display a svg file in browsers including IE8.

The svg is created in Visio and includes a style tag. I have no control on how this file is built.

Is there a way to render it in IE8?

What I have tried and doesn't seem to work:

- [svgweb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/): I couldn't get it to work, and based on the docs it doesn't support embedded style
- [Ready Set Raphael](http://www.readysetraphael.com/): similar issue, it seems that the style tag is ignored

Comment: Traditionally the solution for IE was to use the [Adobe SVG plugin](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/adobe-svg-viewer-download-area.html)

Comment: @RobertLongson I am hoping to find a solution that will work for any visitor, without requiring the plugin install.